# awk - search and replace special character string

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I am trying to find and replace the following string:

```
~|~\N
```

```
pete@computer:~$ cat test.txt 
one~|~two~|~\Nthree
```

Knowing that the pipe character is a special character I escape it. I also escape the escape character below. My attempt goes here:

```
pete@computer:~$ awk '{gsub(/~\\|~\\\N$/, "~|~"); print}' test.txt 
one~|~two~|~|~Nthree
```

The expected result is:

```
one~|~two~|~three
```

but I'm getting additional "|~" in there. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: Why not replace only `\N` with nothing? `sed 's/\\N//g'`

Comment: @Panki I'm assuming this is data that is later fed into a database which uses `\N` to mean `NULL` (`~` is used as an quoting character, and `|` is the field delimiter). Removing all `\N` may be the wrong thing to do as some fields possibly _should_ be `\N`. However, the suggested approach in the question, to match the field delimiter before the `\N` would in that case also break the data. To properly solve this, the error in the code that _produces_ the data should be fixed.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks, learned something new today. Guess this should have been stated in the OP.

Comment: You started out right by identifying that `|` and ```\``` are regexp meta chars that need to be escaped but then instead of just escaping them as `\|` and ```\\``` you chose to add a second set of backslashes turning it into `\\|` and ```\\\``` which is no longer escaping the original `|` and ```\``` but is now escaping the ```\``` you added to escape those chars and so unescaping them and thereby making them metachars again. You then added a `$` to the end of your regexp so the part after the `|` could now only match at the end of the line when you wanted it to match everywhere on the line.

Comment: If you tell us what made you think you had to add those extra ```\```s and `$` we could help explain the flaw in that logic to help you avoid similar issues in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{ gsub(/~\|~\\N/, "~|~") }1' infile
```

single escape is needed for special characters in *regex* argument to the sub()/gsub()/gensub() functions and also you would need to remove the `$` that is end-of-match anchor.

---

when you used `/~\\|~\\\N$/`, it matches two regexes `~\` or `~\N` but second matches only if it was at the end of the line which `$` telling; so according to these you have only `~\` that can match on your input based on the regex and that `~\` is replacing with `~|~` and produce below output:

```
one~|~two~|~|~Nthree
           ^^^
```